# Why not trigger the TypeError when `this == null`

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, polyfills

```
Array.prototype._find = function(callbackfn, thisArg) {
  if (this == null) {
    throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined')
  }
  if (typeof callbackfn !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('callbackfn is not a function')
  }

  for (let i in this) {
    if (callbackfn.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this)) return this[i]
  }

  return undefined
}

console.log(Array.prototype._find.call(null, x => x > 21))
```

This is a Array.prototype.find polyfill, what I except is trigger TypeError when run `console.log(Array.prototype._find.call(null, x => x > 21))`, I'm confusing why not trigger TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running your function in "non-strict" mode. As per the documentation:

> `function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)`
>
> `thisArg`
>
> Optional. The value of this provided for the call to a function. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: **if the method is a function in non-strict mode, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object** and primitive values will be converted to objects.

<sub>[From the MDN page on Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Syntax), emphasis mine</sub>

Here's an example. The first block runs in strict mode and will log `null`. The second one will log `window`, since that's the global scope for your browser. (Please give the stack snippet some time to log the window object, it's quite slow)

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  function logThis() { console.log("strict:", this); }
  
  logThis.call(null);

}());

(function() {
  
  function logThis() { console.log("non-strict:", this); }
  
  logThis.call(null);

}());
```